# Wait for two conditions simultaneously Helium

Tags: java, selenium, helium

I'm using these three lines:

```
waitUntil(Text("WAIT").exists, 900);    
switchTo("Testing");
click(Point(995, 440));
```

I'm waiting for this text to show up, then it clicks a button in a different tab, but what if I want to have it listen for "Go" simultaneously and have it click a different button?

```
waitUntil(Text("GO").exists, 900);  
switchTo("Testing");
click(Point(1100, 440));
```

I have no way of knowing which will show up first. I've tried working around with if conditions, but I can't seem to work quite how I want it to. Any ideas on how to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting two if statements in a refresh loop, which "works", but it's not ideal. It's slow (too slow) and sometimes it just quits. Any other ideas?

```
public static void repeatScript() 
{
    refresh();

    if (Text("WAIT").exists())
        wait(); 

    if (Text("GO").exists())
        go();   

    repeatScript();

}
```